# Find the volume of ball using variable substitution

Tags: calculus, volume

$B = \left\lbrace \,
          (x, \; y, \; z)  \;
       \left| \; \; \;
           \rule{0pt}{12pt}
       \right.
       (3 x + 3 y +  z)^2 \;+\;
       (3 x +  y + 3 z)^2 \;+ \;
       ( x + 3 y + 3 z)^2 \;
       \leq \; 4 \; \right\rbrace$

Find the volume of $B$.

My attempt :

$u = 3 x + 3 y +  z, v = 3 x +  y + 3 z, w =  x + 3 y + 3 z \implies u^2+v^2+w^2\leq 4$.

The jacobian is $|J|=28$ hence:

$u=r\cos\theta \sin \varphi, v=r\sin\theta \sin\varphi, w=r\cos\phi$

The jacobian is $r^2\sin \varphi$.

$\displaystyle \iiint_{B} \mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz =\iiint 28 \,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm dw = \int _{-2}^2\:\int _0^{2\pi }\:\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:28r^2\sin\phi \:\mathrm d\phi \:\mathrm d\theta \:\mathrm dr $

My solution isn't correct and I can't figure out.

Any help is welcome , thanks !

Comment: I think you want $\frac1{28}$ in your integral instead of $28$.

Comment: Also, the radius must always be positive, so you want to integrate r from 0 to 2

Comment: Why is $\phi$ running from $0$ to $\pi/2$?

Comment: Why is $r$ running from $-2$ to $2$? Should not it run from $0$ to $2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the jacobian transformation correctly, what you would have is :-

$$\int_{u^{2}+v^{2}+w^{2}\leq 4}\frac{1}{28}\,dudvdw$$

Which is $$\frac{1}{28}\cdot\text{Volume of sphere of radius 2}=\frac{4\cdot 2^{3}\pi}{3\cdot28}=\frac{8\pi}{21}$$

If you want to use spherical polar coordinates to calculate the volume , then the limits for integral would be $0\leq r\leq 2$ , $0\leq \theta<2\pi$ and $0\leq \varphi \leq \pi$

I suggest you look at the below picture to see why it is the case:-

[image]